Add a python script as windows service
I am using python 3.12 and pywin32 308 build to register a script as a service. I run windows 11.
I have a project with the following path and I launch it from venv in that folder: C:\web\myapp-django-fullstack-main
I've laucnhed postinstall script and the service has registered in windows but when I try to lauch it I get 1053 error. The service didn't response timely. What do I do wrong? Python is not my professional language, I am just tinkering around.
I tried copying from C:\Program Files\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pywin32_system32\pywintypes312.dll and copy it into C:\Program Files\Python312\Lib\site-packages\win32
As well as tried adding environment variables to my computer leading to .venv\Lib\site-packages\pywin32_system32\
Here's the script:
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import os.path
import sys
import site

if sys.executable.lower().endswith("pythonservice.exe"):

    # Change current working directory from PythonService.exe location to something better.
    service_directory = os.path.dirname(__file__)
    source_directory = os.path.abspath(service_directory)
    os.chdir(source_directory)

    # Manually activate a virtual environment inside an already initialized interpreter.
    venv_base = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(source_directory, ".venv"))
    site_packages = os.path.join(venv_base, 'Lib', 'site-packages')
    site.addsitedir(site_packages)

# This is my base path
base_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
if not base_path in sys.path:
    sys.path.append(base_path)

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "crosstab.settings")
    
import win32serviceutil
import win32service
import win32event
import time
import servicemanager

class MyService(win32serviceutil.ServiceFramework):
    _svc_name_ = 'PythonServiceTest'
    _svc_display_name_ = 'Python Test Service'

    def __init__(self, args):
        win32serviceutil.ServiceFramework.__init__(self, args)
        self.stop_event = win32event.CreateEvent(None, 0, 0, None)
        self.running = True

    def SvcStop(self):
        self.ReportServiceStatus(win32service.SERVICE_STOP_PENDING)
        win32event.SetEvent(self.stop_event)
        self.running = False

    def SvcRun(self):
        while self.running:
            print('Скрипт работает...')
            time.sleep(60)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    if len(sys.argv) == 1:
        servicemanager.Initialize()
        servicemanager.PrepareToHostSingle(MyService)
        servicemanager.StartServiceCtrlDispatcher()
    else:
        win32serviceutil.HandleCommandLine(MyService)

